# Creating a field that lists the fields with null values in each row

Tags: sql, database

I have written a SQL query that selects rows from a table conditional on whether that row has an empty field entry, with the fields to check specified. I have not thought of a better way to do that than to check whether each field from the list of fields is empty individually, row by row.

My main issue, however, is that I would like to add an additional field whose entries are the names of the fields that have null values in that row, but I haven't figured out how to do this. Does anyone have a way to do it?

Here's the SQL script I have so far:

```sql
SELECT 
    full_name, ssn, dob, num_adults, num_children, 
    yrs_apt, pa_num, street_number, street, unit, 
    city, zip, rent, proceeding, lt_index, language,
    referral_source, income, eligibility_date, dhci, 
    posture, service_type, housing_type, outcome_date, 
    outcome, services_rendered, activities,
    id AS pika_link,
    ssn, dob, yrs_apt, pa_num, street_number, street, 
    unit, city, zip, rent, lt_index, language, income, 
    posture, service_type, housing_type, outcome_date, 
    outcome, services_rendered, activities AS possible_missing_cols
FROM 
    cap_housing_all_cases_fy22
WHERE 
    (ssn IS NULL) 
    OR (dob IS NULL) 
    OR (yrs_apt IS NULL) 
    OR (pa_num IS NULL) 
    OR (street_number IS NULL) 
    OR (street IS NULL) 
    OR (unit IS NULL) 
    OR (city IS NULL) 
    OR (zip IS NULL) 
    OR (rent IS NULL)
    OR (lt_index IS NULL) 
    OR (language IS NULL) 
    OR (income IS NULL) 
    OR (posture IS NULL) 
    OR (service_type IS NULL) 
    OR (housing_type IS NULL) 
    OR (outcome_date IS NULL) 
    OR (outcome IS NULL) 
    OR (services_rendered IS NULL) 
    OR (activities IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement it sounds like you could concatenate a series of *case expressions*, such as

```
trim (
  case when ssn is null then 'ssn ' else '' end ||
  case when dob is null then 'dob ' else '' end ||
  case when... etc
) as NullColumns
```

Comment: Yes! That's very helpful, thank you so much.